# First call to await-able asynchronous function is synchronous for unknown reason

Tags: c#, wpf, httpclient, async-await

I'm currently playing around with WPF 4.5 and Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview. I'm using the async-await stuff to perform http requets asynchronously in application event handler. The problem is that first call to await-able method hangs the application thread until it's finished. All subsequent calls are okay, i.e. while they're performed application remains usable.

Here is my code (only meaningful excerpts):

XAML

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox FilterMode="None" 
                         Margin="5,0,5,0" 
                         x:Name="textArrival" 
                         Populating="textArrival_Populating"
                         SelectionChanged="textArrival_SelectionChanged"/>
```

C# code-behind:

```
private async void textArrival_Populating(object sender, PopulatingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            textDeparture.ItemsSource = await model.ProcessStationRequest(textArrival.Text); 
            textArrival.PopulateComplete();
        }
```

await-able call source from previous piece of code:

```
public async Task<object[]> ProcessStationRequest(string request)
        {

        // omitted: preparing the request into MemoryStream outputStream
        // ...    

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(hostName, outputStream);

        // omitted: parsing the XML response to an object responseContainer 
        // and returning its member Items, which are of type object[] 
        //...

        return responseContainer.Items;

        }
```

When I'm debugging and setting breakpoint right after line ...await httpClient.PostAsync..., I see that it's really this call which is hanging my application during the time when request is processed (about 2 seconds). But if I'm putting my breakpoint right on the line with awaitable call, it happens immediately after population of autocomplete textbox is started. There is nothing in between, at least in my code, that's why I'm assuming that it's await-able call to httpClient makes my app hang.

Can you point some problem in this code which causes such a strange behavior?

Comment: VS2011 has async-aware debugging. So I don't think the async code you posted is hanging your application; the debugger just won't break until the method is resumed.

Comment: @StephenCleary, thanks for the info, I'll keep it in mind. But nevertheless, I experience the hang in my application. When I'm setting break-point on the line of await-able call to httpClient, it become hit without any delay. However, when I'm setting break point right after the await-able call, I see the delay, and application is hanged during that time. Okay, I understand that second break-point *alone* hit doesn't confirm my guess about the real hang reason, but combined with non-hang on a breakpoint before that call, I suspect, it does. I'll edit the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably running into a known issue with `HttpWebRequest`. The "asynchronous" methods on this object are not actually (fully) asynchronous. :(

For now, I'd recommend wrapping the `PostAsync` in a `Task.Run`.

I've [brought this issue up to the WCF (`HttpClient`) team](http://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/267781) and the async team is also [looking into it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-en/async/thread/9f75f92c-9a51-4921-bad5-97c2b15870bd). No real response as of yet.